Pandas and SQL Summing Dollar Amounts Differently
I am trying to recreate an SQL query I wrote using Python and Pandas. I am not super familiar with SQL so there may be something obvious that I am missing. I am simply trying to sum rows where the 'question' is 'Dollar Amount', then group by subdomain. But I keep getting vastly different results. I am using MySql.
The SQL Queries: (They both result in the same result below)
SELECT subdomain,
       SUM(CAST(REPLACE(answer, '$', '') AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) AS amounts
FROM (
    SELECT subdomain, answer, entry_date
    FROM assessments AS a
    WHERE question = 'Dollar Amount'
      AND answer IS NOT NULL
      AND answer != ''
      AND DATE(entry_date) BETWEEN '2024-07-01' AND '2024-09-30'
      AND entry_date = (
          SELECT MAX(entry_date)
          FROM assessments
          WHERE form_submission_id = a.form_submission_id
      )
) AS latest_entries
GROUP BY subdomain
ORDER BY amounts DESC;

SELECT subdomain, SUM(CAST(REPLACE(answer, '$', '') AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) AS amounts FROM assessments
WHERE form_name LIKE '%-support-services-fund%'
    AND question = 'Dollar Amount'
    AND answer IS NOT NULL
    AND answer != ''
    AND DATE(entry_date) BETWEEN '2024-07-01' AND '2024-09-30'
GROUP BY subdomain
ORDER BY amounts DESC;

The first 5 rows of output:
subdomain 1,82263.89
subdomain 2,74560.26
subdomain 3,28501.65
subdomain 4,8764.40
subdomain 5,8493.30

The python Script
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

def create_db_engine():
    # Database connection details
    user = 
    password = 
    host = 
    port = "3306"  
    database = 

    # Local SSL file paths
    ssl_args = {
        "ssl": {
            "ca": ,
            "cert": ,
            "key": ,
        }
    }

    # Create engine with SSL connection
    engine = create_engine(
        f"mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}",
        connect_args=ssl_args
    )

    return engine

engine = create_db_engine()

table_df = pd.read_sql_table(
    "assessments",
    con=engine,
    columns=[ # a list of all column names as strings (I'm redacting this)
            ],)

ssf = table_df[table_df['form_name'].str.contains('support-services-fund')]

date_1 = '2024-07-01'
date_2 = '2024-09-30'
date_restricted_ssf = ssf[ssf['entry_date'].between(date_1, date_2)]


# Filter strictly for rows where 'question' matches 'Dollar Amount' exactly
ssf_filtered = date_restricted_ssf[date_restricted_ssf['question'] == 'Dollar Amount']

# Convert answer values to numeric, ensuring only relevant rows are processed
ssf_filtered['amounts'] = pd.to_numeric(ssf_filtered['answer'].str.replace('$', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')

# Group by 'subdomain' and sum the amounts
grouped_df = ssf_filtered.groupby('subdomain', as_index=False)['amounts'].sum()

# Sort the results by 'amounts' in descending order
result_df = grouped_df.sort_values(by='amounts', ascending=False)

# Display the results
print(result_df)


The first 5 rows of Python output:
               subdomain   amounts
1            subdomain 1  66734.00
6            subdomain 2  61436.02
8            subdomain 3  28501.65
3            subdomain 5   8053.67
5            subdomain 6   5739.55


Can you add sample input data?

In your pd.to_numeric temporarily change errors to 'raise' to see what you might be losing. You might accidentally be losing valid numbers because of unexpected formatting. Also, it's interesting that subdomain 3 matches the sql output.

@amance Thanks for the suggestion. When I changed it I get this: ValueError: Unable to parse string "$242.93" at position 8.
not sure why It would not be able to parse that string...

Got it. Remove the regex=True part.

Also make sure to add .copy() every time you create a new df from an existing df using slicing or indexing. That way changes to one don't affect the other. Copy isn't needed if you use groupby to create the new df.

If you really want to keep regex=True then you need to escape the dollar sign like this: .str.replace(r'\$', '', regex=True)

I got it! Removing the regex=True made this error appear: ValueError: Unable to parse string "1,000.00" at position 415. So I added these two lines prior to converting to a number:
ssf_filtered['answer'] = ssf_filtered['answer'].str.strip()
ssf_filtered['answer'] = ssf_filtered['answer'].str.replace(',', '')
Now the outputs matches SQL exactly. Can't believe I didn't think to filter out commas.

@amance, if U r on pandas >1.5 and CoW is turned on, you don't need to copy; pandas does that for u

@sammywemmy oh cool I wasn't aware, thanks

Update the pd.to_numeric line to:
ssf_filtered['amounts'] = pd.to_numeric(ssf_filtered['answer'].str.replace(r'\$|\,', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')

